# fixed length array in scanf.Warning with format

Tags: c, warnings, string-formatting, scanf

So I have typedefed the following :

```
typedef char array[25];
```

In my code somewhere I call scanf like this :

```
scanf("%s",array);
```

But I get the warning that %s was expecting a char* while I pass a char*[25].Is there any way to get rid off this warning ?

Comment: bizarre with what you are posting `array` is a type and not an object. So this shouldn't work at all. Please show us the real lines of your code.

Comment: GCC refuses to compile this for me... Is this your actual code? If so, how did it compile?

Answer (score 0):

`array` is type and is not a object. you can not pass it as argument in the `scanf`

```
array a;
scanf("%s", a);
```

Comment: Ok im sorry for this.I have declared a variable of type array,which lets say its a.The correct scanf that i use is scanf("%s",a) and then i get the warning.Im really sorry,if had compiled the above code i would definetly get an error.What can i do to get rid off the erro now  ?

Answer (score 0):

[typedef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef) defines a data type so that you can use it to define different variables with same data types.
like:

```
typedef char employee[25];
typedef char customer[25];
employee a, b;
customer y, z;
printf("Enter first employee's name: ");
scanf("%s",a);
printf("Enter customer's name: ");
scanf("%s",y);
```

though the datatypes are same, but defining them is elaborating things.
all you need to do here is: take `array a;` and then `scanf("%s",a);`

Hope you are clear to the core! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your code is abbreviated...

The actual reason for the warning is that the compiler knows two things: you have a char array that is limited length, and that scanf will scan as many characters as are given in the original string; potentially overflowing the array provided for them.

This is a real issue: the compiler is quite correct.

The solution is to specify the scanf format better. In this case I would suggest using "%24s"  to tell scanf the max number of characters to read for that format element.

Remember to allow for the null terminator - better, explicitly zap array[len-1] with 0.

There are possibly better ways to read the string than scanf. Look into some of the token based methods, for example.

HTH, Ruth